# Call an Action Method From View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

Here is the Action Method

```
[HttpGet]
[ViewException]
[UserFilter(OpUserAuthType.Admin, OpUserAuthType.Normal)]
public ActionResult YorumEkle(string id, string pid)
{
    .....
}
```

It has a view. But from another view, I want that action method to be called by an onclick event or anything to be clicked on. For instance:

```
<a href="" onclick="">Call YorumEkle Method</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ActionLink HtmlHelper like this...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Call YorumEkle Method", "YorumEkle", new {@id = "hello", @pid="yarg!"}, null))
```

It will generate the link you need.

Comment: It didn't work. Action Method "YorumEkle" in a controller called CvAramaController which is inside the Controller folder. The view I am calling the action method is located under Views/Cikti/Sablon. Do you think that may cause a problem. By the way the controller has the Post Action Method with the same name.

Comment: If the action is in a different controller, then you'll need to specify that using a different ActionLink overload.  `@Html.ActionLink("Call YorumEkle Method", "YorumEkle", "CvArama", new { @id = "hello", @pid = "yarg!" }, null))`

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment but building on top of Cj's answer you can also specify which controller the action is on:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action Name","Controller", new {@id = "hello", @pid="yarg!"}, null)
```

In your case

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "YorumEkle","CvAramaController", new {@id = "hello", @pid="yarg!"}, null)
```

Comment: This is from Global.asax: new { controller = "CvArama", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pid = UrlParameter.Optional });
            routes.MapRoute("CvArama", "cv-arama/{action}/{id}/{pid}". Do you think that puts the things in the wrong direction?