# How to call View method and pass parameter to method?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of categories in the Sidebar.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li><a href="~/Books/Category/@item.Title">@item.Title</a></li>
}
```

And I want to display the products of this category by clicking on the category. To do this, I implemented the method ViewCategory.

```
public ActionResult ViewCategory(string name) { ... }
```

But I do not know how to pass the parameter correctly. I'm trying to write something like that, but I understand that doing something wrong ...

```
@Html.Action("ViewCategory", "Books", new {Title=item.Title})
```

Help me please

UPDATE

I have a View Index, and a method in which I bring up a list of my products

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = WebApiClient.GetAsync("Books").Result;
        var booksList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BookDto>>().Result;
        return View(booksList);
    }
```

I need to display only products that belong to this category when choosing a category. I list the categories with PartialView

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @*<li><a href="~/Books/@item.Title"></a></li>*@
    @Html.Action("ViewCategory", "Books", new { name = item.Title })
}
```

To do this, I wrote a method that I try to use instead of

```
    public ActionResult ViewCategory(string name)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseBooks = WebApiClient.GetAsync("Books").Result;
        List<BookDto> booksList = responseBooks.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BookDto>>().Result.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < booksList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (booksList[i].CategoryName != name)
            {
                booksList.Remove(booksList[i]);
            }
        }
        return View("Category");
    }
```

But now I have NullReferenceException...

Comment: have u tried your code is any error or exception?

Comment: you have to rename your action method parameter to `Title` bcoz in `@Html.Action` you set parameter name as `Title` , like `public ActionResult ViewCategory(string Title) { ... }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an Action Method From View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403416/call-an-action-method-from-view)

Comment: I updated my question. Please look at it

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
@Html.Action("ViewCategory", "Books", new {Title=item.Title})
```

to

```
 @Html.Action("ViewCategory", "Books", new {name = item.Title})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as following.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ViewCategory", "Books", 
    new {param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2" }); }
```

Comment: If this is the answer you're looking for, please mark it as answered so that others know this is the solution that worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
@Html.Action("Controller","Name", new { name = item.Title })
```